# Is it possible to access the saved data programmatically in a .rpt file, using existing crystal jar/java api?

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I have a .rpt file with saved data. I need to access the values in group tree Nodes. I am using crystal jar/java api for this. Is it possible?

Using the same api , I am able to export the report to .pdf/.xls and also able to view the report in a jframe.

Any help/lead will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the database the report uses?  If you do, you might have more success querying it directly and taking the crystal report out of the process.  If you can query that database in some manner that produces the same dataset the report uses, then you could use the JTree component of Swing without having to access the report's saved data.

Comment: Thanks R. McMillan.I am having access to the database, but the requirement is not to query it directly, as the data is already present in the .rpt file. Plus if I query the database directly for only one column, increased cost wont get approval